# convergence sequence $\left(\frac{\ln(n+p)}{\ln(n)}\right)^{n\ln(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis

limit as $n \to \infty$ of the  sequence $$\left(\frac{\ln(n+p)}{\ln(n)}\right)^{n\ln(n)}$$

I tried to apply logarithm and to use l´hopital

limit as $n \to \infty$ of $$\frac{n\ln(n)*(n\ln(n)-(n+p)*\ln(n+p))}{(n+p)*\ln(n)*\ln(n+p)*(-\ln(n)-1)}$$

but I do not know from here

I made a chart for p between 1 and 7 and the sequence converges. Help me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

1) $\ln(n + p) = \ln n + \ln (1 + {p \over n}) = \ln n + {p \over n} + o({p \over n})$

2) $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + x)^{a/x} = e^a$.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you so much!! I could get the limit...