# How do you solve $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)^{n\log(n)}$

Tags: limits, analysis, infinity, indeterminate-forms

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)^{n\log(n)}$

As it’s an indetermination, I’ve tried to do

$\exp\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(n\log(n))\cdot(\log(n+1)/\log(n)-1)\right)$.

Limit is equal to $e$ but I don't know how to make the exponent limit $0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I ve tried to do e^lim of (nlog(n))*(log(n+1)/log(n)-1)

Comment: But it gives me infinite and it's meant to be 0

Comment: It can't possibly be $0$: $\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}>1$, and $n\log n>0$. So it's always greater than $1$.

Comment: I mean the limit is e^0, o it's one. But for that the limit of the exponent lim of (nlog(n))*(log(n+1)/log(n)-1) has to be 0

Comment: You actually want$$\exp\lim_{n\to\infty}[\ln\ln(n+1)-\ln\ln n]n\ln n.$$

Comment: @J.G., you are right and the OP’s limit is igual to $e$.

Comment: @Angelo Agreed:$$\ln\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}\sim\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}-1=\frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln n}\sim\frac{1}{n\ln n}.$$

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1308093/42969.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\left(\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)^{n \log(n)}=\left(1+\dfrac{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}{\log(n)}\right)^{n \log(n)}=\left(1+\dfrac{\log(1+\dfrac{1}{n})}{\log(n)}\right)^{n \log(n)}=\left(1+\dfrac{\log(1+\dfrac{1}{n})}{\log(n)}\right)^{\dfrac{\log(n)}{\log(1+\dfrac{1}{n})} \times n \log(1+\frac{1}{n})}$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\log(1+\dfrac{1}{n})}{\log(n)}=0,\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log(1+\frac{1}{n})=1$$